# Qual a funcionalidade dessa linha de código?

Tags: python, c++, arduino

Estou tentando traduzir o seguinte código para C++:

https://github.com/JohanLink/Ball-Balancing-PID-System/blob/master/pythonCodes/interface.py

Queria entender o que a seguinte linha faz:

```
ser.write((str(dataDict[(alpha,beta)])+"\n").encode())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tá vamos lá

`ser.write()` é para "escrever" na porta serial.

`str()` é para converter o valor para string.

`dataDict[]` é um dicionário.

`"\n"` é para pular uma linha.

`encode()` é para converter para um set em bytes

Em resumo, esse trecho manda na serial o resultado da conversão `str()` do dicionário  concatenado com uma quebra linha, convertido em bytes.

Obs: A função `.write()` só funciona com bytes, por isso a necessidade do `.encode()`, e este só funciona com strings, por isso o `str()`

Comment: Acho que está mandando só um valor do dicionário associado à chave `(alpha, beta)` + a quebra de linhas, mas eu posso estar errado.

Comment: Sim, por isso é um dicionário

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é que sua resposta dá a impressão que o dicionário inteiro está sendo convertido para uma string: Ao invés de escrever "uma conversão `str()` **do dicionário** concatenado com uma quebra de linha" eu usaria "uma conversão `str()` **do valor associado a tupla `(alpha, beta)` no dicionário `dataDict`** concatenado a uma quebra de linha". Faz sentido?